# How to view the versions available in yum

Tags: installation, centos, yum

I'm trying to find a specific version of node.js (npm) to install on a CentOS machine. I want a specific version so that new members of our team aren't all running different versions of node.js than everyone else (which is a duh in production development). So I want to make sure I'm installing a specific version via yum, not just the latest.

The first step for me is figuring out how to see what versions of a package are available in yum - the second step being to figure out how to install that specific version via yum.